# how to compare dates in different data frames and assign values to a same column in one dataframe of a same column in another dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a sample data frame like given below

Dataframe1.

```
  general_id                date
    6              2000-01-02 16:57:13
    2              2000-01-02 19:26:13
    3              2000-01-04 13:30:13
    2              2000-01-04 19:03:13
    7              2000-01-06 16:32:13
```

Dataframe2.

```
  general_id                date
    1              2000-01-02 16:57:12
    1              2000-01-06 16:57:12
    1              2000-01-02 19:26:12
    1              2000-01-02 19:26:12
    1              2000-01-04 13:30:12
    1              2000-01-04 13:30:12
    1              2000-01-04 19:03:12
    1              2000-01-04 19:03:12
    1              2000-01-06 16:32:12
```

there is just a second difference in both date columns of the data frames.
i want to compare the date columns of both the data frames and assign the values of `general_id` column in Dataframe1 to `general_id` column in Dataframe2

```
     date1 <- Dataframe1$date-dsecond(1)
     date2 <- Dataframe1$date

     if(date1==date2){
       dataframe2$general_id=dataframe1$general_id
     }
```

but i'm getting this error,

```
In if (date1 == date2) the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Desired Output is:

Dataframe1

```
          general_id                date
            6              2000-01-02 16:57:13
            2              2000-01-02 19:26:13
            3              2000-01-04 13:30:13
            2              2000-01-04 19:03:13
            7              2000-01-06 16:32:13
```

Dataframe2

```
             general_id                date
               6              2000-01-02 16:57:12
               6              2000-01-06 16:57:12
               2              2000-01-02 19:26:12
               2              2000-01-02 19:26:12
               3              2000-01-04 13:30:12
               3              2000-01-04 13:30:12
               2              2000-01-04 19:03:12
               2              2000-01-04 19:03:12
               7              2000-01-06 16:32:12
               7              2000-01-06 16:32:12
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using. Also, your desired output is, in both cases, just Dataframe1 again. Can you modify your example to show why we can't just use `Dataframe2 <- Dataframe1`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: It looks like you want to do a `join_*` on your data: `dplyr::left_join(Dataframe2, Dataframe1,  by = 'date')`, then select the right `general_id` column.

Comment: but there is just a 1 second difference in dataframe2, how do i need to compare that.

Answer (score 0):

The operation you want to carry out here is known as a `join`, specifically you want to `left_join` df2 with df1 so you keep all rows in df2 and then add matching  columns from df1.

To learn more about Joins and how to use them in R, please read this related question: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

The complication here is the fact that the `date` columns are off by one second. To work with that, we just need to modify `date` using `lubridate::dseconds` before joining.

First, we take your data and ensure that `date` is formatted as `POSIXct` using `lubridate::as_datetime` so we can work with it as a date.

This will give us the following dataframes based on your data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(general_id = c(6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 7L), date = structure(c(946832233, 
946841173, 946992613, 947012593, 947176333), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(general_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), date = structure(c(946832232, 947177832, 946841172, 946841172, 
946992612, 946992612, 947012592, 947012592, 947176332), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now we can do a `join`, but notice that we modify `df1$date` within the join by using `dplyr::mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df2, mutate(df1, date = date - lubridate::dseconds(1)), by = 'date')

  general_id.x                date general_id.y
1            1 2000-01-02 16:57:12            6
2            1 2000-01-06 16:57:12           NA
3            1 2000-01-02 19:26:12            2
4            1 2000-01-02 19:26:12            2
5            1 2000-01-04 13:30:12            3
6            1 2000-01-04 13:30:12            3
7            1 2000-01-04 19:03:12            2
8            1 2000-01-04 19:03:12            2
9            1 2000-01-06 16:32:12            7
```

As you can see, we've added the appropriate `general_id` column from `df1`. We can then drop `general_id.x` and rename `general_id.y` if desired. Note that row 2 returns `NA` since it doesn't have a match in `df1` (the time matches, but the day is different)

Answer (score 0):

The following code checks for a time difference between dates in date column of less than 2 seconds. To make it match exactly 1 second of a time difference on only one direction change the `which` statement.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Dataframe2)) {
  corresponding_row <- which(abs(as.POSIXct(Dataframe1$date)-as.POSIXct(Dataframe2$date[i]))<2)
  message('row ', i, ' of Dataframe2 corresponds to row ', corresponding_row, ' of Dataframe1') 
  Dataframe2$id[i] <- ifelse(length(corresponnding_row), Dataframe1$id[corresponding_row], NA)
}
```